# FFmpeg: Add gop/chapters in Mpeg 2 Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd

How can I add multiple exact gop to add exact chapters in dvd authoring?

When you add chapters on the DVD it is not accurate if you do not add at the video encoding.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v mpeg2video -preset veryfast -maxrate 9800k -vf scale=720:480 -aspect 16:9 -r ntsc -an output.mpg
```

Comment: Force key frames at the intended chapter start times: e.g. `-force_key_frames 0,00:07:30,00:21:15,00:34:11,01:02:15` (Why are you writing MPEG-1 PS? Use `-f dvd`)

Comment: Thks, I can replace from time to frames?

Comment: `-force_key_frames expr:'eq(n,0)+eq(n,84)+eq(n,237)'`